# Pass http request as parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm implementing web tokens for my project and I'd like to perform a check after I made a request to see if I need to update my token. Below is an example request:

```
Future getMessages() async => await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
```

I have a function **attemptRequest(request)**

```
Future attemptRequest(request) async {
  final response = await request();
  ...
}
```

that I'd like to pass in http.get(etc) so that I can run things like

```
Future getMessages() async => await attemptRequest(http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers));
```

What should the datatype of the parameter be? Because when I leave it as dynamic

```
attemptRequest(http.get(params));
```

I get a following error

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'call'
Dynamic call of object has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of '_Future<Response>'
```

I could always make http.get a lambda like

```
attemptRequest(() => http.get())
```

But I wouldn't be able to await it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you could make your lambda `async`; see example 2 below. (One quick tip to find out what a type should be is to look at the output of Dart analysis. You could just set the type to `Function` and the analyser will tell you that `Function` cannot be assigned to `Future<http.Response> Function(Uri, {Map<String, String>? headers})` so now you know what the typedef of the function has to be.)

In version 1, we pass in the function, with its parameters.

In version 2, we pass in a lambda.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final url = 'https://www.pub.dev';
  final headers = <String, String>{};

  await attemptRequest1(Uri.parse(url), http.get, headers: headers);

  await attemptRequest2(() async => http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers));
}

Future<http.Response> attemptRequest1(
    Uri uri,
    Future<http.Response> Function(Uri, {Map<String, String>? headers})
        requestFunction1,
    {Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
  return await requestFunction1(uri, headers: headers);
}

Future<http.Response> attemptRequest2(
    Future<http.Response> Function() requestFunction2,
    {Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
  return await requestFunction2();
}
```